# Easy way to find x y coordinates of mouse?

Tags: java

So basically I'm making a game which main class has a loop that runs 60 times per second

I need an easy way to find the x y coordinates of the mouse so i can draw something over that particular coordinates.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Is it desktop ? Are you using AWT or any other lib ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html

Answer (score 6):

This code wont actually work if you try and run it, but it shows you how to get the position of the mouse X and Y, as integers

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;    

public class testmouse {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        int mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;            
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is broken. You should assign `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` to a local variable, otherwise you could get x and y of different locations.

Comment: @xehpuk I said it was broken in the answer, its meant to be used with a window, or in a loop

Comment: I don't see what you meant by that. Of course your code won't run 60 times per second. Even if it did, this won't change its brokenness because of the reason named above (race condition).

Answer (score 2):

Add a [`MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) to the game area and watch for [`mouseMoved(MouseEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html#mouseMoved%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29).